# How to create a handle for application context in Rust?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

This is a higher level issue, however I'm not sure which features of Rust should be used to refine the question.

Taking the first steps to write a graphical application which has a *tool* API, we might want pass in a `context` argument, which exposes various parts of the application:

```
// Where the data lives.
struct Application {
    preferences: Preferences,
    windows: Vec<Windows>,
    documents: Vec<Document>,
}

// A view on the data to pass to tool-code.
struct AppContext {
    preferences: &Preferences,  // immutable
    window: &Window,            // immutable
    doc: &Document,             // mutable
    // ... real world use case has more vars ...
}

// example use
fn some_tool_uppercase(context: &mut AppContext, options: &ToolOptions) {
    // random example
    for w in context.document.words {
        w.to_uppercase();
    }
    context.window.redraw_tag();
}
```

When writing this, I ran into issues with the borrow checker since the document is also stored in a list of other documents - causing it to be mutable in two places at once.

Just to have my program compile, currently I'm removing the document from the list, running the tool, then adding it back into the document list when the tool is finished.

While in some cases its possible to pass multiple arguments, the example above is simplified. Passing every member of the context as an argument is impractical.

How should the context of an application be wrapped into a type that can be passed into tool code, without causing complications with the borrow checker?

Answer (score 0):

The `&` is used to temporary borrow data to a function. Usually when you need to hold access to data from multiple places in the code, you will need the `Rc` or `Arc` type.

Additionally you may want internal mutability for your data. In this case you will need to wrap it also in `Cell` or `RefCell`.

And if your data is shared between threads you'll also need to wrap it by a `Mutex` or `RwLock`.

Now depending on your use case you need composite all this in your data structure. For more information read: [rust wrapper type composition](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/book/choosing-your-guarantees.html#composition)

your example could look like this:

```
// Where the data lives.
struct Application {
    preferences: Rc<Preferences>,
    windows: Rc<Vec<Windows>>,
    document: Rc<RefCell<Vec<Document>>>,
}

// A view on the data to pass to tool-code.
struct AppContext {
    preferences: Rc<Preferences>,  // immutable
    window: Rc<Window>,            // immutable
    document: Rc<RefCell<Document>>,             // mutable
    // ... real world use case has more vars ...
}

// example use
fn some_tool_uppercase(context: &mut AppContext, options: &ToolOptions) {
    // random example
    for w in (*context.document.borrow_mut()).words {
        w.to_uppercase();
    }
    context.window.redraw_tag();
}
```

or if it is multi threaded:

```
struct Application {
    preferences: Arc<RwLock<Preferences>>,
    windows: Arc<Mutex<Vec<Windows>>>,
    document: Arc<Mutex<Vec<Document>>,
}
....
```

Comment: Is the `RefCell` really necessary in `Arc<Mutex<RefCell<...>>>`? The guard returned by `Mutex::unlock` already gives mutable access to underlying data.

Comment: I think you are right. RefCell is only needed in combination with Rc. `Rc<RefCell<...>>`